# IOS bluetoothManager private framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I tried Bluetooth private framework to connect IOS with non-ios device but it's not scanning the non-ios device.

For the development, I've used XCode 5.1 and trying my test over IOS 7 device.

I tried the same app to scan my android mobile as well as a device/hardware where bluetooth is enable.
Hardware/Device bluetooth working perfectly as my Android mobile able to scan as well as able to connect that device.

I'm waiting for suggestion so I can performed the same at IOS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee) which is a demo implementation of the private `BluetoothManager.framwork`?

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of BeeTee. :)*